# Django ~ WSGIRequest with a form added via get_context_data method

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am getting this error when i visit my page:

> Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

The error kicks in on line "17" of my html, which is the line that outputs form.as_p

The html looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.htm" %}

{% block content %}
{% if story_list %}
    {% for story in story_list %}
        <div class="Story">
            <a href="#">{{  story.title }}</a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No stories are present - enter one below</p>
{% endif %}
<h3>Create a new story</h3>
<form action="/addStory" method="post">
    {%  csrf_token %}
    {{  form.as_p }} ***THIS IS LINE 17***
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is i have a view that does *two* things, and from the django tutorials overrode the get_context_data method to add the second item to the django context. Because, um, that's what i'm meant to do, riiiiiiiiight?

```
#for showing of the stories!
class StoryShowView(ListView):
    model = StoryForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        return getStoryItemsForUser(self.request)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StoryShowView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = createNewStoryForm(self.request)
        return context
```

Where, well, the method createNewStoryForm just does this:

```
def createNewStoryForm(request):
    return StoryForm(request)
```

and StoryForm is just this:

```
class StoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        ordering = ['create_date']
```

and the Story model is a normal model, that probably isn't part of the problem, but, hey, i am a cutting and a pasting, so here goes!

```
class Story(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    title =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_closed = models.BooleanField()
    is_random = models.BooleanField() # for uncategorised stories. Only one of these.
    result = models.CharField(max_length=20) #how did the relo work out?
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

UPDATE:
ah, it was the line::

```
return StoryForm(request)
```

I take it i can either pass in a "request.POST" or nothing, is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're right and you were passing `request` instead of `request.POST`, `reqest.GET` or `request.REQUEST` to the constructor of your form. See the doc on [how to use forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#using-a-form-in-a-view):

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('contact.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems that I can see. The easy one being that you can simply replace this line:

```
context['form'] = createNewStoryForm(self.request)
```

with

```
context['form'] = StoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Finally shouldn't this:

```
class StoryShowView(ListView):
    model = StoryForm
```

Be:

```
class StoryShowView(ListView):
    model = Story
```

Comment: oh, is the model to be the Story, and not the (derived) StoryForm?

Comment: Yes, since `StoryForm` is not a model. List view takes a model and then returns an object in the context called `object_list` with items from a queryset (which you can override by `get_queryset()`). In your template you simply iterate over `object_list`.